# Compiler optimizations on map/set in c++

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

Does compiler make optimzation on data structures when input size is small ?

```
    unordered_set<int>TmpSet;
    TmpSet.insert(1);
    TmpSet.insert(2);
    TmpSet.insert(3);
    ...
    ...
```

Since since is small using hashing would be not required we can simply store this in 3variables. Do optimization like this happen ? If yes who is responsible for them ?

edit: Replaced set with unordered_set as former doesn't do hasing.

Comment: `map` and `set` don't do hashing.  That said, I've not seen a compiler that will optimize small containers by itself.

Comment: There is no way to say on behalf of all compilers. Some may optimize something that others do not. They may also all behave differently depending on optimization options passed to them.

Comment: Try it out on [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/). It will show you what assembly will be generated. (But I doubt they will)

Comment: What if you were reading the data from a file?  How would the compiler know if you are reading 3 items, or 3 million items into the set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible **in theory** to totally replace whole data structures with a different implementation.  (As long as escape analysis can show that a reference to it couldn't be passed to separately-compiled code).

But in practice what you've written is a call to a constructor, and then three calls to template functions which aren't simple.  That's all the compiler sees, not the high-level semantics of a set.

Unless it's going to optimize stuff **away**, real compilers aren't going to use a different implementation which would have different object representations.

If you want to micro-optimize like this, in C++ you should do it yourself, e.g. with a `std::bitset<32>` and set bits to indicate set membership.

It's far too complex a problem for a compiler to reliably do a good job.  And besides, there could be serious quality-of-implementation issues if the compiler starts inventing different data-structures that have different speed/space tradeoffs, and it guesses wrong and uses one that doesn't suit the use-case well.

Programmers have a reasonable expectation that their compiled code will work somewhat like what they wrote, at least on a large scale.  Including calling those standard header template functions with their implementation of the functions.

Maybe there's some scope for a C++ implementation adapting to the use-case, but I that would need much debate and probably a special mechanism to allow it in practice.  Perhaps name-recognition of `std::` names could be enough, making those into builtins instead of header implementations, but currently the implementation strategy is to write those functions *in C++* in `.h` headers.  e.g. in libstdc++ or libc++.